# I could not send the mail by using the attachement in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, email

I had created the dropdown list with fields Lab,Pharmacy,Food and Nurse.When I select the lab it generates the new fields and when I select the pharmacy it generates the new field with upload button.I need to send the mail with these details for lab and pharmacy.

By using below mail function I can send only for lab but when I select pharmacy I could not send any mail.Please help me

```
<?php

$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Lab') {
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider' => 'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.islab=?', '1'
    );
} else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Pharmacy') {
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider' => 'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.ishospital=?', '1'
    );
} else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Gym') {
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider' => 'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isgym=?', '1'
    );
} else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Food') {
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider' => 'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isfood=?', '1'
    );
} else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Nurse') {
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider' => 'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.nurse=?', '1'
    );
} else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Physio') {
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider' => 'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.physio=?', '1'
    );
}
$alldata = $readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
foreach ($alldata as $data) {
    sendMailserviceAction($data['email'], $data['name']);
}

function sendMailserviceAction($email, $pname) {
    //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
    //$location=$_POST['location'];
    $servicetype = $_POST['servicetype'];
    $cemail = $_POST['labemail'];
    $cemail = $_POST['pemail'];
    $cemail = $_POST['femail'];

    if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Lab') {
        $cemail = $_POST['labemail'];
        $servicetype = $_POST['servicetype'];
        $testname = $_POST['testname'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $mobile = $_POST['labmobile'];
        $city = $_POST['rcity'];
        $zipcode = $_POST['labzip_code'];
        $html = '
                <p>Service Type: ' . $servicetype . '</p>
                <p>Testname:' . $testname . '</p>
                <p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>
                <p>Email : ' . $cemail . '</p>
                <p>Mobile Number: ' . $mobile . '</p>
                <p>City:' . $city . '</p>
                <p>Zip Code:' . $zipcode . '</p>';
    } else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Pharmacy') {
        $name = $_POST['pname'];
        $medicine = $_POST['medicinename'];
        $cemail = $_POST['pemail'];
        $mobile = $_POST['pmobile'];
        $city = $_POST['pcity'];
        $zipcode = $_POST['pzip_code'];
        $html = '<p>Service Type:' . $servicetype . '</p> <p> Medicine name: ' . $medicine . '</p>
                <p>Name:' . $name . '</p>
                <p> Email: ' . $cemail . '</p>
                <p>Mobile number: ' . $mobile . '</p>
                <p>City:' . $city . '</p>
                <p>Zip Code:' . $zipcode . '</p>';
    } else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Gym') {
        $name = $_POST['fname'];
        $mobile = $_POST['fmobile'];
        $cemail = $_POST['femail'];
        $city = $_POST['fcity'];
        $zipcode = $_POST['fzip_code'];
        $html = '
                <p>Service Type:' . $servicetype . '</p>
                <p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>
                <p>Email : ' . $cemail . '</p>
                <p>Mobile number: ' . $mobile . '</p>
                <p>City:' . $city . '</p>
                <p>Zip Code:' . $zipcode . '</p>';
    } else if ($_POST['servicetype'] == 'Food') {
        $name = $_POST['fname'];
        $cemail = $_POST['femail'];
        $mobile = $_POST['fmobile'];
        $city = $_POST['fcity'];
        $zipcode = $_POST['fzip_code'];

        $html = '
                <p>Service Type:' . $servicetype . '</p>
                <p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>
                <p>Email : ' . $cemail . '</p>
                <p>Mobile number: ' . $mobile . '</p>
                <p>City:' . $city . '</p>
                <p>Zip Code:' . $zipcode . '</p>';
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) and $_POST['servicetype'] == 'Pharmacy') {

        $image_ext = end(explode('.', $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
        $allowed_ext = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf', 'odt');

        $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1, 100) . rand(1, 100))) . str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $source_upl = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'requestquote' . DS . $uploadfilename;
        if (in_array($image_ext, $allowed_ext)) {
            @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
        }
    }


    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in', "Labwise");


    $mail->addTo($email, $pname);

    $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
    $mail->setBodyHtml($html);
    if (file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'requestquote' . DS . $uploadfilename)) {

        $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'requestquote' . DS . $uploadfilename);
        $ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
        $file->filename = $uploadfilename;
        $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
        $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $mail->addAttachment($file);
    }


    try {
        $mail->send();

        return '<h2> Email Sent.   </h2>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>';
    }
}

echo sendMailserviceAction();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is tested code all email are working without any error.

```
<?php

 if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
        { 

            $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
            $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

            $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
             $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
            if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
                @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
            }
        }
      function sendMailAction($uploadfilename){
       //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
        $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];



          if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab'){
          $name=$_POST['name'];
            $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
          $testname=$_POST['testname'];
          $email=$_POST['labemail'];
             $mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];
           $city=$_POST['rcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['labzip_code'];
        $html=
        '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
       <p>Testname: '.$testname.'</p>
         <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
          <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
        <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
         <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
           <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>
        ';
          }
            else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
          {


     $name=$_POST['pname'];
     $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
     $email=$_POST['pemail'];
     $city=$_POST['pcity'];
     $mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];
        $city=$_POST['pcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['pzip_code'];
     $html=
    '<p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
    <p>Medicinename: '.$medicine.'</p>
    <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
     <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
     <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';

     }
     else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
      {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
     $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html=
    '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
    <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
    <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
     }

      else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
      {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html=
     $html=
      '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
    <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
    <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
     }
        else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
      {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
      $html=
      $html=
      '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
      <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
      <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
      <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
       <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
       <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
       }
       else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
     {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
        $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html=
      $html=
      '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
      <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
    <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
     }



        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


$mail->addTo($email,$name);

$mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
$mail->setBodyHtml($html);
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
    {

      $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
$ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
$file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
$file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$mail->addAttachment($file);
    }



 $mail->send();

 }

//Customer mail
  function sendMailcustomerAction(){
//Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);

if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab'){
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
 $email=$_POST['labemail'];
 $testname=$_POST['testname'];
  $html=

  'Dear '.$name.',

  <p>We have received your order for '.$testname.'. You will be attended shortly.</p>

  <p>Best Regards,</p>
  <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
}
else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
{ $name=$_POST['pname'];
   $email=$_POST['pemail'];
   $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
  $html=

  'Dear '.$name.',

  <p>We have received your order for '.$medicine.'. You will be attended shortly.</p>

  <p>Best Regards,</p>
  <p>Team Labwise.</p>';

}

else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
 {
   $name=$_POST['fname'];
   $email=$_POST['femail'];
   $html=
 'Dear '.$name.',

  <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

  <p>Best Regards,</p>
  <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
 }
 else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
 {
   $name=$_POST['fname'];
   $email=$_POST['femail'];
   $html=
 'Dear '.$name.',

  <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

  <p>Best Regards,</p>
  <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
 }
 else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
 {
   $name=$_POST['fname'];
   $email=$_POST['femail'];
   $html=
 'Dear '.$name.',

  <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

  <p>Best Regards,</p>
  <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
 }
 else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
 {
   $name=$_POST['fname'];
   $email=$_POST['femail'];
   $html=
 'Dear '.$name.',

  <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

  <p>Best Regards,</p>
  <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
 }

  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName($name);
  $mail->setToEmail($email);
  $mail->setBody($html);
  $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
  $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
  $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
//$mail->addBcc("contact@labwise.in");
  $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
       $mail->send();
     //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is    successfully Completed');
     //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
       return '<h2>Your Request has been submitted.Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
     //$this->_redirect('');
       }
       catch (Exception $e) {
     //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
     //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
       return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>';
     //$this->_redirect('');
       }
}

  $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
     if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
     {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.islab=?', '1'
      );
     } else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
     {
       $allrecord =$reaconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.ishospital=?', '1'
      );
      }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
    {
       $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isgym=?', '1'
      );
     }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
      {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isfood=?', '1'
      );
       }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
   {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.nurse=?', '1'
      );
     }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
   {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.physio=?', '1'
      );
   }
      $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
     foreach($alldata as $data)
     {
          sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
     }

     function sendMailserviceAction($ccemail,$pname,$uploadfilename){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);

 //$location=$_POST['location'];
$servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
$cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
$cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
$cemail=$_POST['femail'];

 if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
{
$cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
$servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
$testname=$_POST['testname'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];
$city=$_POST['rcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['labzip_code'];
   $html ='
 <p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
 <p>Testname:'.$testname.'</p>
 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';

  }else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
 {
 $name=$_POST['pname'];
 $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
 $cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
 $mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];
  $city=$_POST['pcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['pzip_code'];
   $html ='<p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p> <p> Medicine name: '.$medicine.'</p>
 <p>Name:'.$name.'</p>
 <p> Email: '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
 }
else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
{
$name=$_POST['fname'];
$mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
 $cemail=$_POST['femail'];
 $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
$html ='
 <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
}
else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
{
$name=$_POST['fname'];
$cemail=$_POST['femail'];
$mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
$city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];

 $html ='
 <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
}



    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
      $mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


  $mail->addTo($ccemail,$pname);

  $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
    $mail->setBodyHtml($html);
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename        ) )
   {

     $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
    $ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
  $file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
  $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
   $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $mail->addAttachment($file);
 }


try {
 $mail->send();

return '<h2> Email Sent.   </h2>';

  }
  catch (Exception $e) {

  return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 

 }

    }
   ?>
```

Comment: It is not priniting any thing

Comment: call this at end of file `echo sendMailAction($uploadfilename);`

Comment: no it is showing same empty page after submission

Comment: is it working for you without any error.

Comment: I am not getting customer message for customer.Can you please check it
I am getting the attachment mail for servicetype:Lab also.I need the mail attachment only for Pharmacy

Answer (score 1):

try that for sending the email just change the `model` and `attachment` code

```
  $mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


$mail->addTo($cemail,$pname);

$mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
$mail->setBodyHtml($html);
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
    {

      $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
$ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
$file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
$file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$mail->addAttachment($file);
    }


$mail->send();
```

**new and tested code**

leave the html before as it is

```
if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
        { 

            $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
            $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

            $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
             $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
            if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
                @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
            }
        }


        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


$mail->addTo($ssemail,$pname);

$mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
$mail->setBodyHtml($html);
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
    {

      $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
$ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
$file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
$file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$mail->addAttachment($file);
    }


$mail->send();
```

with your code

```
<?php
      function sendMailAction(){
       //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
        $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];



          if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab'){
          $name=$_POST['name'];
            $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
          $testname=$_POST['testname'];
          $email=$_POST['labemail'];
             $mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];
           $city=$_POST['rcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['labzip_code'];
        $html=
        '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
       <p>Testname: '.$testname.'</p>
         <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
          <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
        <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
         <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
           <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>
        ';
          }
            else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
          {


     $name=$_POST['pname'];
     $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
     $email=$_POST['pemail'];
     $city=$_POST['pcity'];
     $mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];
        $city=$_POST['pcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['pzip_code'];
     $html=
    '<p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
    <p>Medicinename: '.$medicine.'</p>
    <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
     <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
     <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';

     }
     else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
      {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
     $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html=
    '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
    <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
    <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
     }

      else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
      {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html=
     $html=
      '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
    <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
    <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
     }
        else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
      {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
      $html=
      $html=
      '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
      <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
      <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
      <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
       <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
       <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
       }
       else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
     {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     $email=$_POST['femail'];
     $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
        $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
     $html=
      $html=
      '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
      <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
    <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
     }
    if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
        { 

            $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
            $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

            $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
             $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
            $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
            if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
                @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
            }
        }


        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


$mail->addTo($email,$pname);

$mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
$mail->setBodyHtml($html);
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
    {

      $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
$ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
$file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
$file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$mail->addAttachment($file);
    }

try {
 $mail->send();

return '<h2> Email Sent.   </h2>';

  }
  catch (Exception $e) {

      return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 

  }

        }

      echo sendMailAction();
       ?>
```

for service provider

```
    <?php
  $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
     if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
     {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.islab=?', '1'
      );
     } else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
     {
       $allrecord =$rea  connection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.ishospital=?', '1'
      );
      }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
    {
       $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isgym=?', '1'
      );
     }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
      {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isfood=?', '1'
      );
       }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
   {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.nurse=?', '1'
      );
     }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
   {
    $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.physio=?', '1'
      );
   }
      $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
     foreach($alldata as $data)
     {
          sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
     }

     function sendMailserviceAction($ccemail,$pname){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);

 //$location=$_POST['location'];
$servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
$cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
$cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
$cemail=$_POST['femail'];

 if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
{
$cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
$servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
$testname=$_POST['testname'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];
$city=$_POST['rcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['labzip_code'];
   $html ='
 <p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
 <p>Testname:'.$testname.'</p>
 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';

  }else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
 {
 $name=$_POST['pname'];
 $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
 $cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
 $mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];
  $city=$_POST['pcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['pzip_code'];
   $html ='<p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p> <p> Medicine name: '.$medicine.'</p>
 <p>Name:'.$name.'</p>
 <p> Email: '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
 }
else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
{
$name=$_POST['fname'];
$mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
 $cemail=$_POST['femail'];
 $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
$html ='
 <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
}
else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
{
$name=$_POST['fname'];
$cemail=$_POST['femail'];
$mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
$city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];

 $html ='
 <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
}
 if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and   $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
    { 

        $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
        $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

        $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
         $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
        if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
            @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
        }
    }


    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
      $mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


  $mail->addTo($ccemail,$pname);

  $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
    $mail->setBodyHtml($html);
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename        ) )
   {

     $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
    $ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
  $file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
  $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
   $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $mail->addAttachment($file);
 }


try {
 $mail->send();

return '<h2> Email Sent.   </h2>';

  }
  catch (Exception $e) {

  return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 

 }

    }

   echo sendMailserviceAction();
   ?>
```

Comment: it is not showing any confirmation message and no mails are coming

Comment: forgot about `->loadDefault('email_template')` try this and also uploading the file is working or not?

Comment: file is uploading in folder but no mail is getting

Comment: update the code kindly check it

Comment: No.It is not working

Comment: It is showing confirmation message but the mails are not coming

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: did you add send code i attach that kindly check..

Comment: It is showing the confirmation mesage as your order is succesfully completed but I am not getting any mails

Comment: try this and give feedback..

Comment: No,I am not getting any mails

Comment: remove the attachment part and check you are getting email

Comment: No,I am not getting any mail after removing the attachment code

Comment: please give me reply

Comment: Heloo can u please help me @Qaisar Satti

Comment: @Mouni i will test it later and send you working code right now i cannot test my code..

Comment: can I send you in mail

Comment: no need of that

Comment: @@Qaisar Satti please post the working code.

Comment: this  is working code. now what is problem.just paste it after the file upload.

Comment: the uploaded file is not saving in requestquote folder

Comment: can you paste the updated code?

Comment: file is remove after sending the email.

Comment: add this code working 100%. i tested and working 100%

Comment: No.I am not getting any mail.I added the code with your code.Please check it and suggest me modifications

Comment: use last  code i added..

Comment: yes same code i added.I attached the code in my question

Comment: i added in answer use that...

Comment: I need to add confirmation message.Can you please add it

Comment: mail is going??????????

Comment: yes.It is working.But it has to show confirmation message on my page

Comment: do me favor accept my all answer on ur question if they help you in that and i will update code..

Comment: Ok.Please update code with confirmation message.

Comment: code update check it ...........

Comment: for service provider code it is not working.Can you please change My code.Just now I updated for service provider code

Comment: The attachment is not getting for service provide code.Please suggets me.

Comment: set it check it now. and it will work for that too...

Comment: for service provider the mails are not coming in emai]

Comment: check the database query is working properly because all code are same only the $eamil is $ccemail for sending email.

Comment: yes I changed but it is not working.After attachment code it is not working

Comment: remove the attachment code and check and kindly optimize ur code use single upload image not repeat it..

Comment: without attachment it is working.but with attachment code is not working

Comment: upload file code out these and pass the filename to function and check..

Comment: No.I am not getting any email

Comment: because in for loop your are uploading file multiple time. i will give you optimize code later..

Comment: When Can I expect the updated code

Comment: send me latest file now..

Comment: the latest is sent in mail

Comment: sent check it feedback me..

Comment: No.It is not working

Comment: are you getting all the mails in the last echo sendservicemailAction().what i have to keep without your email and name

Comment: you don't need to do that remove that code it is for testing purpose and you email are adding from loop.

Comment: and move your function before for loop

Comment: No.I am not getting any mail.

Comment: did you have your id add in database?

Comment: i tested it all the way and kidly check for admin mail that is working or not?

Comment: I am not any mail it is showing empty page

Comment: `echo sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name'],$uploadfilename);` add this your for loop you will get the email..

Comment: `echo sendMailserviceAction($uploadfilename);` pass the file name to function where you are echo it.

Comment: No I am not getting any mail

Comment: did code is printing any thing????

Comment: no nothing is printing.

Comment: @@Qaisar Satti please help me.It is not working for me.

Comment: add new answer kindly check and feedback..

Answer (score 0):

This code is Working for me try this le me know if you have any query

```
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            // file attached
            if($post['file']){
                $destination_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS .'uploads'.DS.$post['file'];
                $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
                          file_get_contents($destination_path),
                          Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                          Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                          Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                          $post['file']
                );
            }
            // after file attached
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
```

Comment: where I should place this code in my code

Comment: can you give reply

Comment: In your controller where $post['file'] is file and $destination_path is file path

Comment: I have not created any controller file

Comment: http://www.labwise.in/devel/serviceform/submit

you have to put this code in submit action in serviceform controller

Comment: from form to it is redirect to mail.phtml code in that where i should place once chey my code code in mail.phtml

Comment: can you please suggest me where i should place this code exactly.It is not working for me.

Comment: r u receive any data and file in mail.phtml and r u magento developer ?

Comment: yes I can recieve data from mail.phtml and I am a magento developer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32209/discussion-between-vaibhav-ahalpara-and-mouni).

Comment: ok then comment you code for mail and put my code and edit valid data 

my code is working fine for and my live project 

http://technaclip.demo.brainvire.com/index.php/contacts